# how to disable the automatic mapping of std::vector<std::vector<double> > to tuple of tuples in swig python?

Tags: python, swig

Apparently, swig transform automatically `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` to a tuple of tuples. I want to prevent this, and I want the type to be kept as is. How can I achieve it? I tried specifying a definition for the type

```
%template(StdVectorStdVectorDouble) std::vector<std::vector<double> >;
```

but apparently it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Two techniques:

1. `%clear` the typemap for the type before the function is processed by SWIG.
2. Declare the `%template` *after* the function is processed by SWIG.

#### Example 1

```
%module x

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4211 4701 4706)
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%template(vd) std::vector<double>;
%template(vvd) std::vector<std::vector<double> >;
%clear std::vector<std::vector<double> >;

%inline %{
#include<vector>
std::vector<std::vector<double> > func()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > temp;
    std::vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(1.5);
    temp.push_back(a);
    return temp;
}
%}
```

#### Example 2

```
%module x

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4211 4701 4706)
%}

%include <std_vector.i>

%inline %{
#include<vector>
std::vector<std::vector<double> > func()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > temp;
    std::vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(1.5);
    temp.push_back(a);
    return temp;
}

%}

%template(vd) std::vector<double>;
%template(vvd) std::vector<std::vector<double> >;
```

#### Result (of both)

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import x
>>> x.func()
<x.vvd; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< std::vector< double,std::allocator<double > > > *' at 0x00000000025F6900> >
```